Determining for which values $\alpha$ and $\beta$ an $n$-step probability converges
I am having some trouble with the following problem

Consider the Markov chain $(X_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ with state space $I = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and transition matrix
\begin{equation*}
P = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 - \alpha - \beta & \alpha & \beta \\
0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
for $\alpha, \beta \geq 0$ such that $\alpha + \beta \leq 1$. Determine for which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the probability $p_{12}^{(n)}$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I thought of two possible answers but one says that the probability converges while the other doesn't. In a previous question I calculated the invariant distribution of the Markov chain, which is $\pi = (\pi_{1}, \pi_{2}, \pi_{3}, \pi_{4}) = (0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{6})$.
At first I thought that we may write \begin{align*}& p_{12}^{(n)}= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 2 \mid X_{0} = 1) = h_{1}^{\{2, 3, 4\}}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 2 \mid X_{0} \in \{2, 3, 4\}) \\ & = h_{1}^{\{2, 3, 4\}} \cdot \pi_{2} = \frac{1}{2}h_{1}^{\{2, 3, 4\}}\end{align*}
Where $h_{1}^{\{2,3,4\}}$ is the probability of hitting $\{2,3,4\}$ starting in state $1$. Now you could reason or calculate that $h_{1}^{\{2, 3, 4\}} = 1$. Hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{n} = 2 \mid X_{0} = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$.
Secondly, I thought the following: we can go from state $1$ to state $3$ or $4$ with probability $\alpha + \beta$. Then we go to state $2$ with probability $1$ and back to state $3$ or $4$ and the process repeats. Wouldn't $p_{12}^{n}$ then alternate between $0$ and $1$, and thus not converge.
Perhaps both approaches are wrong, or one of them is right. If the latter is true, what would the fault in the other solution be? Any help is appreciated.

Noting that the characteristic polynomial of $P$ is $x^4-x^2$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
&P^2=P^4=P^6=P^8=\cdots\\[4pt]
&P^3=P^5=P^7=P^9=\cdots\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence when $n$ is even with $n\ge 2$ we get
$$
p_{12}^{(n)}=p_{12}^{(2)}=\alpha+\beta
$$
and when $n$ is odd with $n\ge 3$ we get
$$
p_{12}^{(n)}=p_{12}^{(3)}=1-\alpha-\beta
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{12}^{(n)}
$$
exists if and only if $\alpha+\beta={\large{\frac1{2}}}$.
